Calculating the determinant of a matrix that is a modification of the identity matrix
Problem Description
Consider the following $n \times n$ matrix:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
   \phantom{-}1  & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
   -1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
   -1 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
   \phantom{-}\vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
   -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
   \end{vmatrix}$$
This matrix is constructed by adding a row of ones to the top of an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$  identity matrix and a column of negative ones to the left.
Conjecture and Example
Through experimentation, you can conjecture that the determinant of this matrix is always equal to $n$. For instance, with $n=5$ the determinant is indeed $5$:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
   \phantom{-}1  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
   -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
   \end{vmatrix}$$
But I was not able to prove the general result using mathematical induction, expansion by minors or some known property about determinants.
Context
I encountered a matrix with this structure in the proof of Theorem 5.3.1 in Casella and Berger's Statistical Inference (2nd ed, p. 219). Since the book's focus is on probability and statistics, the authors likely assume the reader has the necessary linear algebra background and don't provide a detailed explanation of the determinant calculation.
Question
How can you prove this result for the general $n \times n$ case?

This has been solved here (have a look).

Add the last column to the first one, then the previous column to the first one etc. In the end you have a diagonal determinant.

Thank you Gribouillis. It was easy. I didn't see it!!!! Can you specify what you point out as an answer so I can accept it?

Compare with this post.

If we add columns 2 to n to the first column, we get the triangular determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix}
   \phantom{-}n  & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
   \phantom{-}\vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
   \end{vmatrix} = n$$
